# Issue when updgrading itext version from 2.x to 5.5.13

Tags: itext

I am using itext 5.5.13. I have an existing pdf file and I am trying to add some data to the acrofields in the pdf file using java. Here is my code. This is working perfectly when I use itext 2.x but not with 5.5.13. After the pdfStamper.close() the remaining part of the code is not getting executed and it is directly going to the finally block of the code where this method is being called.

```
private byte[] get1099PdfForm(RI1099DataDTO ri1099DataDTO) throws Exception {
log.debug("Enter generateForm()");
byte[] imageData = null;
PdfReader pdfReader = null;
PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;
File newFile = null;
try {
//New Pdf file
int randomNum = new Double((Math.random() * 1000000)).intValue();
newFile = File.createTempFile(String.valueOf (randomNum), ".pdf");
newFile.deleteOnExit();

//String year = DateUtils.toString(new Date (), "yyyy");

//Read existing pdf template
pdfReader = new PdfReader(ri1099DataDTO.getTax_Year() + "_" + _templateName);

//Create instance of Pdf Stampler
pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream(newFile, false));

//Get acro fields
AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.getAcroFields();

//Map form fields
this.mapFormFields(pdfFormFields, ri1099DataDTO);

//Set form flattening to true
pdfStamper.setFormFlattening(true);

// close the pdf
pdfStamper.close();
 //Return stream
imageData = new byte[(int) newFile.length()];
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(newFile);
fileInputStream.read(imageData);
} catch (Exception e) {
log.error("Error occured while generating form for job <TaxYear=" + ri1099DataDTO.getTax_Year() + "/Compay=" + ri1099DataDTO.getCompany() + "/TaxID", e);
throw e;
}
log.debug("Exit generateForm()");
return imageData;
}
```

Comment: *"After the pdfStamper.close() the remaining part of the code is not getting executed and it is directly going to the finally block of the code where this method is being called."* - that sounds like some exception or error is thrown. Is there something in the logs? Otherwise try catching `Throwable` instead of `Exception`.

Comment: What finally block? I don't see any. Normally it would look like this  `try{...}catch(Exception e){...}finally{...}`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my issue by removing xercers jar by adding this to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>xerces</groupId>
<artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
<version>2.0.2</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```